# API Gateway export API definition with Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I was checking out a couple methods from [amazon-api-gateway-developer-guide](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-api-gateway-developer-guide/tree/master/doc_source) and I stumbled with [api-gateway-export-api](https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-api-gateway-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/api-gateway-export-api.md), I managed to get the AWSCLI command (`aws apigateway get-export --parameters extensions='apigateway' --rest-api-id abcdefg123 --stage-name dev --export-type swagger latestswagger2.json --profile profile --region us-east-1`) working by adding the --profile and --region parameters, but for whatever reason I can't get the Request URL to return the API definition response.

**I am trying to do the following couple things (Postman):**

- GET request with the URL: https://apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/restapis/abcdefg123/stages/dev/exports/oas30
- Add authorization type AWS-Signature to the request with all the
  parameters filled (AccessKey, SecretKey, AWS Region,
  Service Name and Session Token)
- The Authorization, x-Amz-Date and x-Amz-Security token are generated successfully, as far as I can tell
- I am also sending a the headers Host (apigateway.us-east-1.amazonaws.com) and Accept (application/yaml)

This results in the following error:

> {"logref":"2734hu2r2873","message":"User:
>   arn:aws:sts::7216832187:assumed-role/DEVELOPER/xxxx is not authorized to perform:
>   apigateway:GET on resource:
>   arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/abcdefg123 /stages/dev/exports/oas30"}

I was actually getting the same error with the AWSCLI command before I added the --profile and --region parameters. I already checked out a couple posts about issues like mine, this one is an example [export swagger api definition from api gateway via http request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855489/export-swagger-api-definition-from-api-gateway-via-http-request), but I am doing basically the same thing (sending the same headers, same host and URL) and getting this error. I don't think my access key, secret key, token or any of that information might be wrong... because it's the credentials I use for the AWSCLI command.

Thank you for the taking the time to read and/or reply to my post, I really appreciate any feedback in anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of trying to get this request to work is that I wanted to add it as an HTTP proxy to an API, unfortunately I couldn't get it to work.
My problem was that I have a couple profiles in my session and each one of them has different permissions, I found no way to specify the profile I wanted to use in the request and thus it caused the error mentioned above.

In the end I opted to write a Lambda function with proxy integration and everything went fine, after giving the lambda profile the apigateway:GET permission.

If I have a misconception about anything I wrote about or I am using a term in an incorrect way please correct me, I am still fairly new to AWS and have a lot to learn!